# Always show scrollbar even if the widget is wider than the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app in flutter with support for the web, in one screen i have a table that can be very large so i nested two SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable in both ways. Now i'm trying to set a ScrollBar to each SingleChildScrollView but the problem is that the nested SingleChildScrollView shows the ScrollBar only when the end of the widget is reached, but i want both ScrollBar to be always visible, how can achieve this?

Code:

```dart
Scrollbar(
              controller: _horizontalController,
              thumbVisibility: true,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  controller: _horizontalController,
                  child: Scrollbar( //! This scrollbar is only shown when the other reach the end
                    controller: _verticalController,
                    thumbVisibility: true,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      controller: _verticalController,
                      child: /*******************/,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the default `notificationPredicate` of `Scrollbar` is defined as:

```
bool defaultScrollNotificationPredicate(ScrollNotification notification) {
  return notification.depth == 0;
}
```

Therefore, since the depth of the second `Scrollbar` is 1 (because it is nested), and the default predicate only checks for 0, you do not see the nested `Scrollbar`'s thumb.

Solution: Also be notified when the depth is greater than 0.

See comments:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// The default 'notificationPredicate
  return Scrollbar(
    controller: _horizontalController,
    thumbVisibility: true,
    /// Nest the vertical 'Scrollbar' right below the horizontal one.
    child: Scrollbar(
      controller: _verticalController,
      thumbVisibility: true,
      /// Notification.depth == 1 here,
      /// but the default predicate checks whether Notification.depth == 0.
      notificationPredicate: (notification) => notification.depth >= 0,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: _horizontalController,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: _verticalController,
          child: Container(
            width: 800.0,
            height: 1200.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```